# problema al restaurar una bd de sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

buen dìa con todos, era lo que me esperaba, logré instalar el sql 2008 r2 pero al parecer los 5gb que tengo es mucha data para mi versión express, pero hay algo que no entiendo, en la versión express dice que su capacidad es alrededor de 10gb pero bueno, claro está en este pantallazo, alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto para poder restaurar mi bd que es con un fin educativo, o si es que la única forma es de tener el sql licenciado. Gracias. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La version 2008 R2 express no soporta los 10GB, creo que lo aumentaron en 2012 o 2014. Te sigo recomendando que actualices la versión.

Comment: @LuisCazares pero el sql 2008 r2 es compatible con el sql 2012 o 2014 ? podré restaurar mi bd sin problemas? y como mencionaba, mi data es más de 5gb

Comment: Una base de datos la puedes restaurar en una versión superior, pero no en una inferior. Revisa mi respuesta en tu pregunta anterior para más detalles.

Comment: Acabo de revisar bien tu imagen, dice que el tamaño supera los 10GB.

Comment: Si son datos productivos, necesitas pagar una licencia o usar una versión de prueba. Si no son datos productivos, puedes utilizar la edición Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando la version EXPRESS del SQL SERVER, cambia a la version ENTERPRISE o STANDARD para poder restaurar tu base de datos.

Fuente:

[Ediciones y características de SQL SERVER](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017)